# Get textfields values in dynamic tableview

Tags: uitableview, tags, uitextfield, nsindexpath

I have a Dynamic table view which has 5 prototype cells, inside each cell I have 6 textfields. I´m tagging the textfields but I´m having trouble understanding **How can I get the values from all of them** in the "`textFieldDidEndEditing`". 
In my code I have this:

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
NSMutableArray *cellOneContentSave = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *cellOneTexfieldOneTxt;
if (textField == [self.view viewWithTag:1503])
{
cellOneTexfield1Txt = textField.text;
[cellOneContentSave addObject:cellOneTexfieldOneTxt];  
}
```

**Problem 1:** BUT! this only get´s me the value from one texfield in cell one...Should I be using a switch for each cell and texfield?.

**Problem 2:** I said it was a dynamic tableview, so the user can insert news rows(per section) pressing the green + button that appears on the left side when he enters the commit edit style...and when he enters, should the tag´s of the newtexfields have different tag´s?. In one hand I think not, because it´s new texfields BUT different indepaxth.row....but in the other hand I don´t know if the controller demands new tag´s...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // assuming your text field is embedded directly into the table view
    // cell and not into any other subview of the table cell
    UITableViewCell * parentView = (UITableViewCell *)[textField superview];

    if(parentView)
    {
        NSMutableArray *cellOneContentSave = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSString *cellOneTexfieldOneTxt;

        NSArray * allSubviews = [parentView subviews];
        for(UIView * oneSubview in allSubviews)
        {
            // get only the text fields
            if([oneSubview isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]])
            {
                UITextField * oneTextField = (UITextField *) oneSubview;

                if(oneTextField.text)
                {
                    [cellOneContentSave addObject: oneTextField.text];
                } else {
                    // if nothing is in the text field, should
                    // we simply add the empty string to the array?
                    [cellOneContentSave addObject: @""];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // don't forget to actually *DO* something with your mutable array
    // (and release it, in case you're not using ARC), before this method
    // returns.
}
```